# Are there some certain cases where wife can disobey her husband?

Tags: wife, husband

I know that the wife must be obedient to her husband and it makes sense. Since family is like an organization there must be someone in charge. I do not see any oppression or problem in this.

But what if the husband is in the wrong? Or the husband is telling the wife to do something that is sinful? Or let's say some relative of the wife is sick and she wants to go see that relative but her husband refuses to give her permission. Can she speak up in an acceptable manner? Is there any other case where the wife can protest or disobey her husband?

Another thing, can the wife tell her husband not to mix with certain persons she doesn't like?

Answer (score 2):

The prophet (pbuh) said: "There is no obedience to any created being if it involves disobedience towards the creator"
You must obey Allah and the husband shouldn't tell you to do something to disobey Allah.

Also, surah 2:228 “And they (women) have rights (over their husbands as regards living expenses) similar (to those of their husbands) over them (as regards obedience and respect) to what is reasonable”
This shows that the women also have rights over their husbands. The husvand should try to do what is best for the wife being the head of the family and should try to choose wise decisions. You may suggest something to him and if he disagrees then show him some Quran verses such as the one above to maybe prove a point. If he knows that there is a danger to what you are doing or something that is not right it may just be best to follow it.